# Get all inherited classes of a generic abstract class

Tags: c#, inheritance, abstract

I'm looking for some way to get all classes that inherit a generic abstract class, and perform a method on each of those classes.

I've been following this [Change parameter type when implementing an abstract method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11015152/change-parameter-type-when-implementing-an-abstract-method) to have the class implementations I want, something similar to this:

```cs
public abstract class AbstractRequest<TResponseData>
                where TResponseData : IResponseData
{
    public abstract void Search();
    public abstract GoodData BindData(TResponseData data);
}

public interface IResponseData
{
}

public class AResponse : IResponseData
{
}

public class BResponse : IResponseData
{
}

public class A : AbstractRequest<AResponse>
{
    public override void Search()
    {
        // get AResponse
        // Call to BindData() with AResponse
    }
    public override GoodData BindData(AResponse data)
    {
        // Bind the data from AResponse to GoodData
    }
}

public class B : AbstractRequest<BResponse>
{
    public override void Search()
    {
        // Get BResponse
        // Call to BindData() with BResponse
    }
    public override GoodData BindData(BResponse data)
    {
        // Bind the data from BResponse to GoodData
    }
}
```

This is working find, until I need to get all the A & B class and invoke the `Search()` method for each of the classes. With a non-generic abstract class, I could use the following snippet to get the classes

```cs
var instances = from t in Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes()
                where t.IsSubclassOf(typeof(AbstractRequest))
                    && t.GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes) != null
                select Activator.CreateInstance(t) as AbstractRequest;
```

Then, how can I get all the classes A and B that inherit from `AbstractRequest<AResponse>` and `AbstractRequest<BResponse>`?

**Edit:** I forgot to mention. Let's assume that there will be many implementations similar to A or B, and will be added over time. I would like to have an "elegant" (if possible) solution so later on, I only need to take care of the implementation C, D, etc.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually getting the instance to invoke Search() (and only search) can be done by breaking up the abstract class:

```
public abstract class AbstractRequest
{
    public abstract void Search();
}

public abstract class AbstractRequest<TResponseData> : AbstractRequest
            where TResponseData : IResponseData
{
    public abstract GoodData BindData(TResponseData data);
}
```

And then you can use your original (non-generic) code:

```
var instances = from t in Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes()
    where t.IsClass &&
          typeof(AbstractRequest).IsAssignableFrom(t) &&
          t.GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes) != null
    select Activator.CreateInstance(t) as AbstractRequest;
```

**(Old, busted solution)**

I think that I would do something like this (untested):

```
var abstractRequestTypes =
    (from t in Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes()
     where t.IsClass &&
          typeof(IResponseData).IsAssignableFrom(t)
     select typeof(AbstractRequest<>).MakeGenericType(t)).ToList();

var instanceTypes = from t in Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes()
    where t.IsClass &&
          abstractRequestTypes.Any(dt => dt.IsAssignableFrom(t));
```

This should cover anything in the inheritance hierarchy, taking advantage of the type constraint on `AbstractRequest`.

Comment: Man, your edited answer is exactly what I need!!! Tested, and worked perfectly fine in my case. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 4):

Something like this should do the trick:

```
from t in Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes()
where t.IsClass && 
      (typeof(AbstractRequest<AResponse>).IsAssignableFrom(t) ||
       typeof(AbstractRequest<BResponse>).IsAssignableFrom(t))
select t;
```

Or if you wanna get all classes that inherit from generic class `AbstractRequest` you can use:

```
from t in Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes()
where t.IsClass && 
      t.BaseType != null &&
      t.BaseType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(AbstractRequest<>)
select t;
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I forgot to mention that it's just 2 of the many implementations similar to A or B, and will be added over time. This will definitely work, but I would like to have a more elegant solution so later on, I only need to take care of the implementation C, D, etc.

Comment: it does allow typeof(AbstractRequest<>) , what you said is only true when instantiating the type.

Comment: @VikasGupta VS 2013 doesn't report it as a compiling error so I think it's possible.
@Selman22 I apologize if my next question is dumb but I'm new to C#. Then how can I construct and instance of `t` and call the method `Search()`? I tried `var i = t.GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes).Invoke(null);` but VS report error on the like I call `i.Search()`.

Answer (score -1):

This has worked for me on a few separate projects

```
/// <summary>
/// Find all subclasses of a given type via reflection
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="T">Parent class type</typeparam>
/// <returns></returns>
public Type[] GetAllSubclasses<T>() where T : class
{
    Type[] types = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes()
                           .Where(t => t.IsSubclassOf(typeof (T))).ToArray();

    return types;
}
```

To instantiate and then execute a method, you can try this pattern:

```
// Create new instances, then use those to execute some method.
foreach (Type T in GetAllSubclasses<MyType>())
{
    MyType mt = (MyType) Activator.CreateInstance(T);
    mt.MyMethod(someArgs);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I think your solution is virtually the same as what I did. The problem is the `MyType` is a generic type (in my case `AbstractRequest<IResponseData>`, and class A and B will inherit from more-specific classes, `AbstractRequest<AResponse>` and `AbstractRequest<BResponse>`.